# How create a model resource and a related many to many resource on a single POST?

Tags: django, api, tastypie

Hi i am using tastypie to expose a rest api on a project, and got stuck on how to implement the endpoint of a resource, so here's my problem:

i have the following models,

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # fields...

class Order(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='OrderProduct')
    # other fields...

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order      = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    product    = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    quantity   = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['order', 'product']
```

and the following resources,

```
class ProductResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'products'
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']

class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    products = fields.ToManyField('agro.api.OrderProductResource', 'orderproduct_set', related_name='product', full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'orders'
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'delete']
        authentication = Authentication() # only for testing purposes
        authorization = Authorization() # only for testing purposes

    class OrderProductResource(ModelResource):
        product = fields.ForeignKey('agro.api.ProductResource', 'product')

        class Meta:
            resource_name = 'orderproducts'
            queryset = OrderProduct.objects.all()
            allowed_methods = ['get']
            include_resource_uri = False
            authentication = Authentication() # only for testing purposes
            authorization = Authorization()  # only for testing purposes
```

when i try to POST to the /orders/ endpoint with the following request data

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "product": "/products/1/",
            "quantity": 4,
            "unit_price": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

i get the following error traceback

```
{
    "error_message": "orderproduct.order_id may not be NULL",
    "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 397, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1165, in post_list\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1784, in obj_create\n    self.save_m2m(m2m_bundle)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1951, in save_m2m\n    related_bundle.obj.save()\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py\", line 463, in save\n    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py\", line 551, in save_base\n    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\manager.py\", line 203, in _insert\n    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py\", line 1593, in insert_query\n    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\compiler.py\", line 912, in execute_sql\n    cursor.execute(sql, params)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\util.py\", line 40, in execute\n    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)\n\n  File \"c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\sqlite3\\base.py\", line 344, in execute\n    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)\n\nIntegrityError: orderproduct.order_id may not be NULL\n"
}
```

as you can see i didn't specified an Order wich the new OrderProduct should relate to, what i am trying to achieve is post an Order resource with it's nested OrderProduct data being created on the same POST request.

And here comes my question how can i specify that the Order referenced by OrderProduct should be the current order being created, what is the most idiomatic approach, overriding hydrate(not sure if at this point i have the django orm order object instance and consequently possible to do so) to set the order of the related model or reimplementing hydrate_m2m or even save_m2m, any sugestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, i really have the order missing but in my case it must be that way this data represents an order to be created and the related data to populate the intermediary table OrderProduct(json products field), so the idea is to the user of the api pass information about the order and the related data on the same request e.g. to create a new order the user will POST with the following data

```
{
    "products": {
        "product": "/products/1",
        "quantity": 4,
        "unit_price": 5
    }
}
```

these data should generate the following database registers

```
Order
    # with and auto generated id

OrderProduct
    order # which points to the auto generated id
    product # points to a previous registered product
```

if i pass the order field i don't have any valid id at this moment(kind of a chicken egg problem) because the order was not yet saved on the database, the tastypie dataflow will save the Order on the ModelResource.obj_save method and that method will call ModelResource.save_m2m that creates the OrderProduct register where the exception happens.

So i need to know which tastypie hook i must implement in order to implicitly set that reference before save_m2m tries to save the OrderProduct.